# EDKII Base Tools Fails to build

Tags: build, uefi, build-tools, edk2

I'm following [this tutorial](https://github.com/tianocore/tianocore.github.io/wiki/How-to-Build-With-Stuart#i-want-to-build-basetools) and, while running `python BaseTools/Edk2ToolsBuild.py -t GCC5` It throws this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path to>\edk2\BaseTools\Edk2ToolsBuild.py", line 188, in <module>
    main()
  File "<path to>\edk2\BaseTools\Edk2ToolsBuild.py", line 184, in main
    Edk2ToolsBuild().Invoke()
  File "<path to>\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\edk2toolext\base_abstract_invocable.py", line 235, in Invoke
    retcode = self.Go()
              ^^^^^^^^^
  File "<path to>\edk2\BaseTools\Edk2ToolsBuild.py", line 159, in Go
    raise Exception("Failed to build.")
Exception: Failed to build.
```

I installed gcc trough MSYS2 MINGW64.

I tried removing the `-t GCC5` argument but it just tried to use VS2015, which I don't have.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That particular error indicates that there was a make build error.

You can review the build logs at:

```
$(workspace)/BaseTools/BaseToolsBuild/BASETOOLS_BUILD.txt
```

to review the make error that is being bubbled up.

If you are still having issues after reviewing the build log, you could post the build log error from here  as a discussion in the repository: [tianocore/edk2 · Discussion](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/discussions), or file a [bugzilla bug](https://bugzilla.tianocore.org/).